# incorrect associations between multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I think I'm screwing up the relationships between my databases.

I have a calendar where I would like for a **user** that has created a **tour** to be able to view **tour requests**.

Another user can view their tour, and decide to book their tour.

A user can book several tours.

My models:

User

Tour

Tour_request

**user.rb**

```
has_many :tours
has_many tour_requests
```

**tour_request.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :tour
```

**tour.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :tour_requests
```

now initially the code I had was:

```
current_user.tour_requests.all
```

however this is wrong, as the people that requested the tour will see it as-well. I only want the people who have the tour to see it. Thus I tried:

```
current_user.tours.tour_requests.all
```

but that gave me an error.

What am I doing wrong? Are my associations fucked up?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `current_user.tours.tour_requests.all` is that `current_user.tours` return `ActiveRecord::Relation` which does not define `tour_requests`. If you just want a list of all tour_requests for all the tours created by the user, you need `has_many :through` association:

user.rb

```
has_many :tours
has_many :tour_requests

has_many :requests_for_own_tours, through: :tours, source: :tour_request
```

Comment: what would the code end up being in the controller? , and the relation from the tour_request to the user if we did it like this?